# Change marker in map clustering android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, markerclusterer

I am using [Map Utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) library for clustering on map. now, i want change default markers which are showing in map like below:

[image]

you can see markers in green circle. i want to change that. i already implemented this. but dont know how to change this. if you anyone know then help to solve this.

Code:

```
@Override
    protected void startDemo() {
        getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(51.503186, -0.126446), 10));

        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, getMap());
        getMap().setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);

        try {
            readItems();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Problem reading list of markers.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void readItems() throws JSONException {
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.radar_search);
        List<MyItem> items = new MyItemReader().read(inputStream);
        mClusterManager.addItems(items);
    }
```

Comment: are you asking about the code for changing Default marker icon?

Comment: something like that. i want to set different marker icons for different items.

Comment: please refer this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker)

Answer (score 10):

You should implement `onBeforeClusterItemRendered` and make your changes by making a custom Renderer class :

```
 public class MarkerClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem> {

    public MarkerClusterRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map,
                                 ClusterManager<MyItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        // use this to make your change to the marker option 
        // for the marker before it gets render on the map
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.
                fromResource(R.drawable.your_custom_marker));
    }
}
```

and Don't forget to add your custom Renderer to your Cluster Manager

```
 mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MarkerClusterRenderer(this, mMap, mClusterManager));
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use it to create custom Marker using this snippet.

```
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
                 position(51.503186, -0.126446).title("mapTitle").snippet("is cool")
                  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                          .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
```

Comment: This is a wrong answer. It changes even cluster's images (yes, Google Maps are buggy).